# Need to make this array of objects function reusable in javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In the map function... if the arrayOfObjects was not "obj.car" but was say "obj.animal" or obj.anything... I don't want to have to change that line for every array of objects I use the function on that has a different property name.  Ultimately the function should take in an array of objects then return an array of values and check for duplicates then return unique array. Thanks in advance. Also I am new and I feel like I shouldn't be using two return statements within one function so any tips much appreciated.

```
const arrObj = [
  { car: "BMW" },
  { car: "Honda" },
  { car: "BMW" },
  { car: "BMW" },
];

const duplicates = (arrayOfObjects) => {
  var finalArray = arrayOfObjects.map((obj) => {
    return obj.car;
  });
  const uniqueSet = new Set(finalArray);
  const uniqueArr = [...uniqueSet];
  return uniqueArr;
};
console.log(duplicates(arrObj));
```

Comment: you're not using two return statements within the one function, the first return is in an arrow function of the map method, whereas the second return is for your `duplicates` arrow-function

Answer (score 1):

Have your `duplicates` function also accept a key, then use bracket notation to look up that key:

```js
const arrObj = [
  { car: "BMW" },
  { car: "Honda" },
  { car: "BMW" },
  { car: "BMW" },
];

const duplicates = (arrayOfObjects, key) => {
  var finalArray = arrayOfObjects.map((obj) => {
    return obj[key];
  });
  const uniqueSet = new Set(finalArray);
  const uniqueArr = [...uniqueSet];
  return uniqueArr;
};
console.log(duplicates(arrObj, 'car'));
```